# How to dynamically change image opacity in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, cross-browser, transparency, opacity

I am using the following code to set image transparency in Javascript, but it only works in Internet Explorer (and in FireFox, Opera, Safari and Google Chrome it remains non-transparent):

```
img = new Image();

img.src = "...";

img.style.filter       = "alpha(opacity=75);";
img.style.MozOpacity   = "0.75;";
img.style.opacity      = "0.75;";
img.style.KhtmlOpacity = "0.75;";
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `;` in the string, which is assumed to be part of the value by the browser and, therefore, results in an invalid number.

You can just use a number for the `opacity` property:

```
img.style.filter       = "alpha(opacity=75);";
img.style.MozOpacity   = 0.75;
img.style.opacity      = 0.75;
img.style.KhtmlOpacity = 0.75;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi-colon from inside the quotes like this:

```
img.style.filter       = "alpha(opacity=75)";
img.style.opacity      = "0.75";
```

or without the quotes all together:

```
img.style.filter       = "alpha(opacity=75)";
img.style.opacity      = 0.75;
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tnDaD/

MozOpacity and KhtmlOpacity should no longer be needed.  The browsers that required those are long, long gone from use.

Answer (score 2):

Don't give the `;` in the value, it'll do that for you :)

```
img = new Image();
img.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png";
img.style.opacity = "0.3";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cdjc6/